# How do I print an equation in visual basic.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make the right-hand side of the equation as text for a label but it isn't working out for me.

`num1` and `num2` are random numbers.

```
Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Start.Click
        Dim max
        Dim num1 
        Dim num2 
        max = InputBox("Geef een maximumwaarde in. ")
        Dim rnd As New Random
        num1 = rnd.Next(0, max)
        num2 = rnd.Next(0, max)

If num1 < (max / 2) Or num2 < (max / 2) Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) + Str(num2))
End If
If num1 > num2 And (num1 - num2) > 0 Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) - Str(num2))
End If
If (num1 * num2) > 0 And (num1 * num2) < max Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) * Str(num2))
End If
If num1 > num2 Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) / Str(num2))
End If
```

Desired output:
if num1=9 and num2=3 and max=60
output would be:
'9+3'
or
'9/3'
etc
with the code i currently have it just solves the equation.

Comment: Are you looking to change the .Caption property of the label?

Comment: Yes. As of this moment the caption of the Label is empty. And when the user chooses a max number, num1 and num2 will be randomly generated and will be between 0 and the max number. I want the equation itself to be the caption.

Comment: "but it isn't working out for me" doesn't tell us in what way it isn't working as desired. If you gave us an example of the input (`max`), how the random numbers are generated, the expected output, and the actual output then we could help you.

Comment: This is how the random numbers are being generated. I don't think there a fault in this. My goal is to print the right side of the equation. So thank you if you could help me figure it out :)

Comment: I *think* you want to code the output in the form `LOpgave.Text = Str(num1) & "+" & Str(num2)`. The `&` operator is to concatenate strings, and `"+"` with the double-quotes makes the `+` into a string instead of an operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    Dim max
    Dim num1
    Dim num2
    max = InputBox("Geef een maximumwaarde in. ")
    Dim rnd As New Random
    num1 = rnd.Next(0, max)
    num2 = rnd.Next(0, max)

    If num1 < (max / 2) Or num2 < (max / 2) Then
        LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " + " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 + num2)
    End If
    If num1 > num2 And (num1 - num2) > 0 Then
        LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " - " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 - num2)
    End If
    If (num1 * num2) > 0 And (num1 * num2) < max Then
        LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " * " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 * num2)
    End If
    If num1 > num2 Then
        LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " / " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 / num2)
    End If
End Sub
```

As was mentioned in a comment on the OP, the `&` operator will concatenate Strings together.  I can't vouch for the rest of code, but the printing seems to be working with this version.

Comment: When you post answers in VB, it is best to make sure that they compile with [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton. Generally, I try to change as little as possible of the OP code while still answering the question.  Should I reconsider that approach?  Here, turning `Option Strict On` would require quite a few changes (removing implicit conversions, adding error handling, etc).  I'm usually torn between just answering the question and really fixing the code to follow best practices.  Can you provide any advice?

Comment: My advice is to set Option Strict On to be the default for new projects and always use it. If there is ever any situation where it genuinely needs to be set to Off then that code can be in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! This was the answer I needed!!!

```
Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
Dim max
Dim num1
Dim num2
max = InputBox("Geef een maximumwaarde in. ")
Dim rnd As New Random
num1 = rnd.Next(0, max)
num2 = rnd.Next(0, max)

If num1 < (max / 2) Or num2 < (max / 2) Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " + " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 + num2)
End If
If num1 > num2 And (num1 - num2) > 0 Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " - " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 - num2)
End If
If (num1 * num2) > 0 And (num1 * num2) < max Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " * " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 * num2)
End If
If num1 > num2 Then
    LOpgave.Text = (Str(num1) & " / " & Str(num2) & " = " & num1 / num2)
End If
```

End Sub